# windows phone 8 orientation control with if statement

Tags: windows-phone-8, orientation

I want to check current orientation of screen with if statement for example.

```
if(orientation==landscape)
{
a++;
}
```

What should i use for this kind of job how can i get my current orientation and check it with if statement.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved my problem

```
  else if (p.X > 10 && p.X < 100 && a >= 1 && Orientation==PageOrientation.Landscape)
            {
                a--;
                link = "cevsen/" + a.ToString() + ".jpg";
            }
```

you can get your current orientation with `Orientation` and compare `PageOrientation.Landscape`